# Why isn't my image displaying in the result file when using PHPSpreadsheet in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, phpspreadsheet

Im trying to add a image into excel file

```
public function renderTest()
    {
        $spreadsheet = IOFactory::load(storage_path('filename.xlsx'));
        $worksheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();

        $drawing = new Drawing();
        $drawing->setWorksheet($worksheet);
        $drawing->setName('User avatar');
        $drawing->setDescription('User avatar');
        $drawing->setPath(storage_path('Picture1.jpg'));
        $drawing->setCoordinates('B48');
        

        $worksheet->getCell('A48')->setValue('it got here!');

        $writer = IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Xlsx');
        $writer->save('testResult.xlsx');
    }
```

and in the result file: its load the "it got here!" but not the image

[image: image not display]

where did i go wrong?